# Android mediaplayer stream not playing

Tags: android, stream, media-player

i'm trying to work with internet radio streams, but on some streams I get nothing except this:

```
05-14 13:16:13.480: E/MediaPlayer(2088): error (1, -2147483648)
05-14 13:16:13.480: W/System.err(2088): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
05-14 13:16:13.480: W/System.err(2088):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
05-14 13:16:13.480: W/System.err(2088):     at com.darko.mk.RadioTresActivity$2.run(RadioTresActivity.java:141)
05-14 13:16:13.480: W/System.err(2088):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Some stations are working fine but some are not playing at all.

Here is my code that gives the error:

```
public void playRadio(final String source) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(source);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare(); //line 141 that gives the error
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

What can be the problem? Here is the souce example:http://217.16.69.17:8000/metropolis.mp3

Comment: what kind of source are you using?

Comment: @AndroSelva here is the source [link](http://217.16.69.17:8000/metropolis.mp3)

Comment: did u try any other link instead of the one you specified here?

Comment: @AndroSelva yes, this link for example is working http://178.32.57.58:8012/

Comment: is this of the same stream type or normal mp3 file

Comment: @androSelva its a stream, but different radio station

Comment: I am not sure whether this will help you. From my knowledge I came to know that stream was really slow. So may be you have to do a work around like this guy http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/ . Try to download byte by byte and play it.

Answer (score 2):

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29)

"For streams, you should call prepareAsync(), which returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been buffered."

```
iplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
iplayer.prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

To Stream audio using Android media player you should start playing audio once you receive onPreparedListner callback.As loading the data into the media player takes time .If you start playing the media player without listening onPreparedListner  media player will Exception.